# Reject value even if one character is not found in regex matching

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of values containing allowed characters i.e.-

```py
ALLOWED_CHARS = """[âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ]"""
```

The above list values and `ASCII` values are allowed, if anything else apart from these comes should give an error.

For combination of `ASCII` and other characters(ex: any Chinese/Japanese) it gives me an error whereas for combination of values taken from `ALLOWED_CHARS` list and other characters(ex: any Chinese/Japanese) it doesn't gives me an error.

Ex:

```
input:
+-----------+
|middle_name|
+-----------+
|  ELIZABET@|
|     ROBERT|
| ELIZABET弟|
|  ELIZABETH|
|  ELIZABETH|
| ELI弟ABEßH|
+-----------+
```

```
Current Output:
+-----------+
|middle_name|
+-----------+
|           |
|           |
| ELIZABET弟|
|           |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

```
Expected Output:
+-----------+
|middle_name|
+-----------+
|           |
|           |
| ELIZABET弟|
|           |
|           |
|ELI弟ABEßH |
+-----------+
```

`ELIZABET弟` contains 弟(Chinese letter) and ascii values and it gives an error, which is correct.
`ELI弟ABEßH` contains 弟(Chinese letter) and ß(present in `ALLOWED_CHARS`) should give an error but it doesn't.

Could you please help me here.

I am checking the above condition for multiple columns

```py
 isAsciiUdf = udf(lambda z: z.isascii())
 for i in colList:
   df = df.withColumn(i, when(isAsciiUdf(col(i)) == "false", col(i)).otherwise(""))
   df = df.withColumn(i, when(~(col(i).rlike(ALLOWED_CHARS)), col(i)).otherwise(lit("")))
```

Here, I am checking first if the column value is non-ascii, I get the column value. Then, I am checking if column values are not present in `ALLOWED_CHARS`, then take those column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALLOWED_CHARS = """âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ"""

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('ELIZABET@',),
    ('ROBERT',),
    ('ELIZABET弟',),
    ('ELIZABETH',),
    ('EßLIZABETH',),
    ('EßLI弟ABEßH',),
    ('弟',)
], ['middle_name'])

df = (
    df
    .withColumn('bad_characters', f.regexp_extract(f.col('middle_name'), f'([^\x00-\x7F{ALLOWED_CHARS}])', 1))
    .where(f.length(f.col('bad_characters')) > 0)
)

df.show()
```

And the output is:

```
+-----------+--------------+                                                    
|middle_name|bad_characters|
+-----------+--------------+
| ELIZABET弟|            弟|
|EßLI弟ABEßH|            弟|
|         弟|            弟|
+-----------+--------------+
```

Explanation of the regex pattern:

1. `^`: Means "Not".
2. `\x00-\x7F`: Represents ASCII characters
3. `{ALLOWED_CHARS}`: Adds the non-ASCII characters that are allowed in f-string format.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but unfortunately it's not working for all the values. The values which are present in `ALLOWED_CHARS` are also getting extracted. Ex values:              
ÍØ«ð

Comment: I just ran a test for the examples, and they are not showing up in the "bad_characters" column. Are you sure you're using `âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ` as ALLOWED_CHARS and not `[âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ]` ?

Comment: I am taking it like this: `ALLOWED_CHARS = """[âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ]"""`

Comment: Thanks!! It's working when I gave `ALLOWED_CHARS = """âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ"""` like this. Also , could you please give some info on regex matching pattern -  `f'([^\x00-\x7F{ALLOWED_CHARS}])` , how does this exactly works.

Comment: @MuskanMakhija I've added explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your ALLOWED_CHARS TO

```
   ALLOWED_CHARS = "^[0-9a-zA-Z_\-@âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ]+$"
```

Your code works !!!Put whatever character you want in between the brackets !!!! I also added the ASCII characters in the ALLOWED_CHARS. For instance:

```
names = df.schema.names
    for name in names:
        df = df.withColumn(name, when(~(col(name).rlike(ALLOWED_CHARS)), col(name)).otherwise(""))
```

Also if you don't wanna keep the rows, you can simply use:

```
 names = df.schema.names
        for name in names:
            df = df.filter(~col(name).rlike(ALLOWED_CHARS))
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering specifically, [rlike()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) seems a much more logical choice.

```py
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [
...         ('ELIZABET@',),
...         ('ROBERT',),
...         ('ELIZABET弟',),
...         ('ELIZABETH',),
...         ('ELIZABETH',),
...         ('ELI弟ABEßH',),
...     ],
...     schema=['middle_name']
... )

>>> 
>>> df.show()
+-----------+
|middle_name|
+-----------+
|  ELIZABET@|
|     ROBERT|
| ELIZABET弟|
|  ELIZABETH|
|  ELIZABETH|
| ELI弟ABEßH|
+-----------+

>>> GOOD_CHARS='âäàáãåçñéêëèíîïìß£¬ÂÄÀÁÃÅÇÑ¦øÉÊËÈÍÎÏÌØ«»ðýþ±°ªºæ¸Æ€µ¯¡¿ÐÝÞ®¢¥·©§¶¼½¾^¨×ôöòóõ¹ûüùúÿ²ÔÖÒÓÕ³ÛÜÙÚ'
>>> df.filter(df.middle_name.rlike(f'[^\x00-\x7F{GOOD_CHARS}]')).show()
+-----------+
|middle_name|
+-----------+
| ELIZABET弟|
| ELI弟ABEßH|
+-----------+

>>>
```

Comment: 弟 will not be present in `ALLOWED_CHARS` list. It's one of the value which shouldn't be allowed in the fields. The values which are present in `ALLOWED_CHARS` and any `ASCII` values should be only allowed. Apart from these if anything comes,  those values should be captured for error

Comment: @MuskanMakhija, and you would think the name `"ALLOWED_CHARS"` would've given the hints. Updated the answer.